# Javascript listener doesn't trigger proxy getter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to manipulate getter in JS classes, I'm using proxy for that.

I've noticed that functions in JS listener trigger proxy immediately, and when the event occurs proxy is not triggered!

see this [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/shamaseen/v56rhtno/5/) to fully understand the case.

why this behavior happens??

I know that if I write the listener this way

`$(document).on('mousemove',function(){
test.method1();
});`

the event will trigger the proxy in the expected way, but is there any other way to trigger the proxy without changing the listener code style (because I have a lot of listeners and it will take a lot of time to change them all)